# Resig's JS Inheritance script... Parent class has properties overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop, inheritance

was just attempting to use JS Inheritance somewhere and have come across a problem with the subclass overwriting properties.
I use an object called options to have default properties that can be overridden. So like so:

```
class a {

   options: {
       property1: 1,
       property2: 2
   },

   init: function (parameters, element) {
       this.options = $.extend({}, this.options, parameters);
   }

}
```

I do it this way because I also use plugin creation... but that's not the problem. The issue is that when you over-ride the base class that also has an options parameter, then it is overwritten and when you call _super in the base class, then it doesn't know what it used to anymore to do what it needs to do.

For example, you have two classes: `Person` and `Ninja`. Upon initialisation of `Person` he eats... hes hungry. `Ninja` extends `Person` and he needs to read a hit list. Even though hes a ninja, he still needs to eat as a Person. So you call this._super(); but he doesn't seem to have any food anymore (which is declared in the options).

Here's a fiddle where you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/37Z8m/5/

The ways I can think of to get around this is to either redeclare the default options that are inside the parent class so they still exist or add an exception to J-Resig's inheritance script to only add to an options class and not override it... It's just that in other languages when you extend, it still has access to it's own properties.

John's inheritance script first overrides the object and then lets you call _super(); which I think is wrong...?

Answer (score 0):

But what if you *wanted* to override the parent options instead of merging? Sounds like you should just use the options directly without the intermediate dictionary:

```
class a {
     options: {
         eat: 'burger',
         drink: 'soda'
     }
}
```

becomes

```
class a {
     options_eat: 'burger',
     options_drink: 'soda'
}
```